# hosted Laravel not storing images

Tags: php, laravel, host

I have a Laravel project hosted in CPanel and it's running but when I upload an image, it supposed to store in the public folder like ("public_path()/posts/theactualimage.jpeg").
the image path is stored in the database  but the real image is actually not stored at all

in my local machine things are going pretty well  but not on the hosted

I don't know if there's any configuration that I should do ...

here is the structure of the folders

```
./
|    public_html
|    |    posts
|    |    index.php 
|    |    some other files
|
|    myapp
|    |    all the other files controllers views ...
```

here is the function that stores the images

```php
public function uploadImage($location, $imageName){
    $name = $imageName->getClientOriginalName();
    $imageName->move(public_path().'/'.$location, date('ymdgis').$name);
    return date('ymdgis').$name;
}
```

I did not use link storage
thank you for your help

Comment: You're not receiving your request in your function. How do you expect it to move the image?

Comment: the images are stores when running on localhost but the problem is actually in the shared host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is missing the key requirement to handle the request. You're not receiving any request in your function upload image. You need to receive a request in your function so that you can process further on that request. Here's a sample code for your better understanding.

```
   /**
     * Storing an Image in public folder.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function uploadImage(Request $request, $location, $imageName)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);
    
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->image->extension();  
     
        $request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
  
        /* Store $imageName name in DATABASE from HERE if you want.  */
    
        return back()
            ->with('success','You have successfully upload image.')
            ->with('image',$imageName); 
    }
}
```

**Store Image in Storage Folder**

$request->image->storeAs('images', $imageName);
// storage/app/images/file.png

**Store Image in Public Folder**

$request->image->move(public_path('images'), $imageName);
// public/images/file.png

**Store Image in S3**

$request->image->storeAs('images', $imageName, 's3');

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, I do have a function that handle the request and call the other function to store the image passed in the request

Comment: I'm gonna try this way to see

Comment: sure. It's just a template to upload image to public path. You can further process it and store the information in your database as per to your requirements.

Comment: Just in case, if you don't know. If you mark it as an answer it'll be a green tick. :) I've not received any notification. Thanks :)